# Default settings for VirtualBox machines?

Tags: virtualbox

How can I change the default settings of virtual machines that are created by VirtualBox? I don't need any floppy devices or sound enabled by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is no such functionality currently available. [This two-years-old forum thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22550) discusses such demand, but even [the latest user manual](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/UserManual.pdf) does not seem to mention any way of doing this.

As a workaround, you can use the `Clone` option. Just create a kind of "template VM" without any storage devices, set the settings to your preference and clone this machine each time instead of creating new ones in the standard way. Of course, add storage to the cloned ones accordingly.

If you'd like a more customized automatic approach or want to quickly create a number of VMs in one go, you can create a command-line script using `VBoxManage` (see the referenced manual above).

Answer (score -1):

I wrote this in the comment but am adding it here

You set the settings you want before you create the machine or after it's created, I don't think there is a "default" machine

I understood that this is not exactly was he was looking for but thought that it would demonstrate what could be done.

[image: Select the machine you want, the click settings]

[image: Browse the options on the left]

Comment: You set the settings you want before you create the machine or after it's created, I don't think there is a "default" machine

Comment: Your comment seems like the real answer; your answer just shows how to edit a specific machine